# Server 2012 - Task Scheduler vbs files stuck at "OpenWith.exe"

Tags: windows-server-2012

Have recently set up a Windows Server 2012 and I have some scheduled tasks I need to set up that run .vbs files. These tasks are running ok on Server 2008 and the run ok when I launch them manually, however running them from Task Scheduler the vbs does not run and stays in "Running" state forever.

When I check Task Manager I see it creates a process called "OpenWith.exe".

It looks like task scheduler doesn't understand the .vbs file extension.

I have set the task to run as my user identity, when I am logged on but I do not see this window appear in my console session.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1):

The answer following some research seems to be that I needed to run the vbs with Cscript instead. Like so:

```
Cscript //nologo  "C:\myscript\script.vbs"
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post:

https://superuser.com/questions/556681/it-opens-open-with-prompt-whenever-scheduled-task-run

I think you need to associate .vbs files with WScript.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Program/script to use on the task.

Action Tab --> Start a Program --> Program/script: CScript.exe

Add Arguments: The location of your vbs file. (C:\VBS\VBSfile.vbs)

Is more easy if you create a .bat file and set the task to run the batch file.
On the batch file, write this:

> cscript.exe C:\FOLDER\YourScript.vbs

Go to the task and set to start a program (batch file name).